# How can I make in sails a query with a where clause and a 'or pairs' clause

Tags: mysql, sails.js

I need to make a query in Sails that need to mix a where clause with a 'or pairs' clause.
By example, the result must be all the records of an especified user (user: $scope.user.id) additionally from this records, only only those who field1 = cond1 OR field2 = cond2 ...

I'm using sails with MySQL.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get you started with **OR** queries: http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/query-language#?or-pairs

```
Model.find({
  user_id: 'xy'
  or : [
    { name: 'walter' },
    { occupation: 'teacher' }
  ]
})
```

This query will take all records containing user_id=xy and additionally filter those records with the **OR** query.